# What did I just click?

Tags: support, answers, user-experience, profile-page

I just answered a question, and before I clicked the `Post Your Answer` button, I also clicked a checkbox that was right above it.

I did not intend to click this checkbox - it's a little early, my eyes aren't open the whole way, etc. I must have seen this checkbox thousands of times by now and have never paid attention to it.

This happened so fast that I don't even know what the checkbox said. **What did I just click?**

If I edit my answer, I do not see the checkbox. If I type a new answer to a different question, I do not see the checkbox.

Googling "stack overflow checkbox below answer" returns a bunch of questions about checkboxes, but not the checkbox I'm looking for.

I vaguely believe I saw the word "email" so my guess is this has something to do with email subscriptions. Is that right? If so, what did I just change? How do I change it back?

Comment: The checkbox there is labelled *community wiki*.

Comment: There is something like “Receive new responses as email”, but I believe this only applies to questions. The checkbox next to answers is “community wiki”, but [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54971135/4642212) isn’t one.

Comment: However, your most recent answer is not a CW answer, so it wasn't checked when submitted.

Comment: There’s also nothing special in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54971135/timeline) or the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54971135/revisions).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the reply. I still see the CW checkbox, and the checkbox I selected isn't that one. The "receive new responses as email" checkbox that Xufox mentioned sounds like what I selected, but I wasn't asking a question.

Comment: Just type in the answer box below to see that it doesn't require a question.

Comment: @HansPassant If I type in the answer box below, I only see the `community wiki` checkbox. I'm guessing that the checkbox I'm talking about **is not shown** after you check it once?

Comment: Question subscriptions are managed on your network profile, at https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=subscriptions, take a look-see there to see if you got subscribed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

If I go to my Stack Overflow profile, then the `Edit Profile & Settings` tab, and then the `Edit Email Settings` link in the left nav, I see this:

---

[image: email settings]

---

Presumably this is a setting for receiving notifications in your email. I am fairly active and have never received an email notification, so I was suspicious that this was set to `Daily` emails.

Sure enough, if I set this to `Off` and then go to post an answer, I see the mystery checkbox again:

---

[image: email checkbox]

---

From a UX perspective, it feels a little weird that this checkbox just **goes away** when you select it and can only be disabled from a completely separate page. But for now at least the mystery is solved. Thanks all.

Comment: Huh, it is only now that I really take notice of the wording and function. I'm upping the ante on strange UX design: why does a checkbox that you see while posting an answer affect you globally :/ This reads like it should only happen for this one answer (except for the pluralisation that I completely read over until now), but **no** - this one checkbox opens the floodgates. (okay: only once a day)